# VBA AutoCAD: drawing polyline from two given points and following a specific path

Tags: vba, autocad, qgis

I'm trying to draw a polyline from two given points and following a specific path (another polyline) otherwise the 2 polylines will be superimposed with VBA AutoCAD or qgis

[image: screenshot]

```
Sub draw_polyline1()
    Dim lineobj As AcadLine
    Dim entite As AcadEntity 
    Dim ptd As Variant
    Dim pta As Variant

    ThisDrawing.Utility.GetEntity entite, ptClique, "select the path to follow" 
    ptd = ThisDrawing.Utility.GetPoint(, "select the start point")
    pta = ThisDrawing.Utility.GetPoint(, "select the end point")
    Set lineobj = ThisDrawing.ModelSpace.AddPolyline(entite, ptd, pta) 
    ZoomExtents 
End Sub
```

The blue line is the path and the red one is the polyline that I want to draw automatically between the 2 points(the stars in the schema)

Comment: Actually impossible to help you with such little data/info from you: you may want to give more explanations and show your code till now

Comment: Sub draw_polyline1()
Dim lineobj As AcadLine
Dim entite As AcadEntity
Dim ptd As Variant
Dim pta As Variant

ThisDrawing.Utility.GetEntity entite, ptClique, "select the path to follow"

ptd = ThisDrawing.Utility.GetPoint(, "select the start point")
pta = ThisDrawing.Utility.GetPoint(, "select the end point")

Set lineobj = ThisDrawing.ModelSpace.AddPolyline(entite, ptd, pta)

ZoomExtents

End Sub

Comment: this code just draw a polyline between the two points but doesn't follow the path

Comment: a polyline, unlike a basic line, can consist of multiple points.  It is my understanding that you will need to provide each coordinate that the polyline will need to pass through.  In addition, if some portions of the path are curved, you will need to define curved segments of the polyline.  I am still working that part out for myself when I get the opportunity so I cant help you much more than cover the concept.

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way is to clone the path You want to follow, and "cut" endings outside clicked point. To cut, You may use command _break, then check which one of the new curves have the start point, end point on selected points.